# Adb starts with an unattached emulator

Tags: android, emulation, adb

When I start Eclipse, I always see emulator-5554 in the Devices View. If I start an application (in automatic target selection mode), it starts on this emulator, but the emulator doesn't have a window. I have to stop the system.process of the emulator every time after Eclipse startup.

I was playing around with adb from the command line, so probably I caused the issue, but I can't figure out, how. 
When I restart adb with the commands 'adb kill-server' and 'adb start-server', emulator-5554 starts again, so adb starts it automatically.

I read [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/adb.html) document, but I couldn't find any information on emulator automatic startup. Neither a google search on "adb autostart emulator" helped.

How can I keep adb from running this emulator at startup?

Answer (score 4):

I was having a similar problem with this non existent  emulator-5554

try this

```
adb kill-server
adb reboot
```

Comment: This problem is long gone for me. It just stopped after a few weeks. But the questions was not how can I stop the device, but how do I stop adb to run it.

Comment: ohh alright . I was having this problem this afternoon , this emulator was there but not added in avds , I came across your question while searching for answer, eventually my problem was solved and I thought it might help you

Comment: This did not work for me. But I checked and I did actually still have bluestacks running in the background. killing bluestacks solved the emulator-5554 for me.

Answer (score 1):

go to task manager- 
Resource Monitor- 
in overview tab click Description to see all BlueStack in the sort- 
kill tree all of them.- 
OR ANY OTHER EMULATOR LIKE BLUESTACK.

Comment: exactly the same, emulator-5554 was bluestack

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem. WORKED FOR ME!

1. Open task manager
2. End any bluestacks processes that appears

Now the problem should be gone.